# Run an encrypted program without saving it with python

Tags: python, memory

I have an AES encrypted file in python. Lets call it `encrypted.exe`.

I have the key for the encryption. I can then use python to decrypt my file (`Cipher` module in python) and obtain `decrypted.exe`. I then save the file (using `write`). Later I can run the file by clicking on it or through a cmd or powershell.

What I want to do is be able to run the `decrypted.exe` without saving it. For instance I thought about, decrypting with my AES key then loading it in the RAM and run it from there.

I don't know how to do it nor if it is possible with python.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can, but it’s more than overhead. It’s really complex task, so I would recommend to save file to hard drive, than use `subprocess` or `os` library to execute it, then delete it.